# Is it possible to embed multilingual text library to iPhone

Tags: iphone, user-interface, fonts, multilingual, user-experience

I am willing to port multi-lingual library to iPhone for text entry. Before i have done using it other platforms like J2me,Symbian.

I used bitmap & scalable custom fonts for platforms other than iPhone. Is it possible to embed my library to ios level or i am restricted to only application tier, so that multilingual text will be available to iPhone address-book, e-mails, etc.

Comment: ... Huh? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+i18n

Answer (score 1):

First Is it possible to embed my library to iOS level or i am restricted to only application tier?

In iOS Platform , applications have restricted within a sandbox environment so what ever you want to do is restricted within application level & it has no effect on iOS level.

Second You can use your own custom font inside an iPhone application.(Thanks iOS 3.2)

From iOS 3.2 doc

**Custom Font Support:**
Applications that want to use custom fonts can now include those fonts in their application bundle and register those fonts with the system by including the UIAppFonts key in their Info.plist file. The value of this key is an array of strings identifying the font files in the application’s bundle. When the system sees the key, it loads the specified fonts and makes them available to the application.

in order to add custom fonts follow these steps:

1)Add your custom font files into your project using XCode as a resource

2)Add a key to your info.plist file called UIAppFonts.

3)Make this key an array.

4)For each font you have, enter the full name of your font file (including the extension) as items to the UIAppFonts array.

5)Save info.plist

6)Now in your application you can simply call [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFontName" size:12] to get the custom font to use with your UILabels and UITextViews, etc…
**Note :** This work only in iOS 3.2 & later iOS.

For list of fonts available in iOS platform you can refer [this](http://iosfonts.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the library at iOs level. The only thing you can do is to add a framework at your application level for multilanguage support.

Comment: I am not sure, what you are saying, being specific yes, i can render my own glymphs from custom fonts in the app. But what i am asking will these fonts be available in addressbook, emails, calendar, etc. ?